# Display results from MySQL database in two columns based on gender

Tags: php, mysql

I want to list the names of participants from MySQL database in two columns based on gender.  I cannot figure out how to start a new column when the gender changes, so currently I just have one column with all the first name and last names displayed and "Male" and "Female" heading separating the names.  How can I get, on change of gender, a new column to start? I want to do this so that when user prints page it can all hold on one page.

Here is the code I am using for the table:

```html
<table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">

<thead>
<tr>
<td><strong></strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong></strong></td>
</tr>
</thead>

<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
if($comp != $row['Gender']) echo "<tr><td colspan=\"6\"><b>".$row['Gender']."</b></td></tr>\r\n";

 
 echo "<tr><td>"; 
 echo $row['rownumber'];
 echo "</td><td>";
 echo "$first2";
 echo " ";
 echo "$last2";
 echo "</td></tr>";
 
 
 
$comp = $row['Gender'];
}
}
echo "</table>";
```

This is the query I use:

```html
$query = "
SELECT 
IF(@prev != tt.Gender, @rownum:=1, @rownum:=@rownum+1) as rownumber, @prev:=tt.Gender, tt.* 
FROM ((
 (SELECT comp1, first2, last2, Gender, DOB, Events, Events2, Events3, ID 
 FROM entries 
 WHERE (comp1='$chooser')
  ) UNION 
 (SELECT comp2, first2, last2, Gender, DOB, Events, Events2, Events3, ID 
 FROM entries 
 WHERE (comp2='$chooser')
  ) UNION
 (SELECT comp3, first2, last2, Gender, DOB, Events, Events2, Events3, ID 
 FROM entries 
 WHERE (comp3='$chooser')
  ))) tt, 
 (SELECT @rownum := 0, @prev:='') r 
ORDER BY Gender, last2 ASC";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$comp = "";
```

Comment: What is $result?  Can you show your query. Going to need more info here to help you.  Add mysql table to your question and the queries that are running up to this point.

Comment: @Bleach  I have included my query